# Encog: weights keep increasing

Tags: java, neural-network, encog

I am trying to train a neural network with Encog library.

Dataset (~7000 examples) before splitting (into training (60%), cross-validation (20%) and testing (20%)) is linearly normalised so that it looks like this:

```
Min=-1.000000; Max=1.000000; Average=-0.077008
```

Target (ideal) dataset (also linearly normalised) looks like this:

```
Min=0.201540; Max=0.791528; Average=0.477080
```

I initialie network like this:

```
mNetwork = new BasicNetwork();
mNetwork.addLayer(new BasicLayer(null, false, trainingDataSet.getInputSize()));
mNetwork.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, numberOfNeurons));
mNetwork.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), false, trainingDataSet.getIdealSize()));
mNetwork.getStructure().finalizeStructure();
mNetwork.reset();
```

I use `ResilientPropagation` trainer (tried `Backpropagation`as well):

```
ResilientPropagation training = new ResilientPropagation(mNetwork, mTrainingDataSet);
for (int i = 0; i < mNumberOfIterations; ++i) {
    training.iteration();
    result.trainingErrors[i] = mNetwork.calculateError(mTrainingDataSet);
    result.validationErrors[i] = mNetwork.calculateError(mValidationDataSet);
    System.out.println(String.format("Iteration #%d: error=%.8f", i, training.getError()));
}
training.finishTraining();
```

During the process of training error reported by the trainer is generally decreasing. After finishing training I dump weights:

```
0.04274211002929323,-0.5481902707068103,0.28978635361541294,-0.203635994176051,22965.18656660482,22964.992410871928,22966.23882308963,22966.355722230965,22965.036733143017,22964.894030965166,22966.002332259202,22965.177650526788,22966.009842504238,22965.971560546248,22966.257180159628,22966.234150681423,-21348.311232865744,-21640.843082085466,-21057.13217475862,-21347.52051343582,-21347.988714647887,-21641.161098510198,-21057.27275747668,-21348.784123049118,-21347.719149090022,-21639.773689115867,-21057.095487328377,-21348.269878600076,22800.304816865206,23090.894751729396,22799.39388588725,22799.72408290791,22800.249806096508,22799.19823789763,22799.85510732227,22799.99965531053,22799.574773588192,22799.57945236908,22799.12542315293,22799.523065957797
```

They usually are either very large or very small. With sigmoid it ends up with predictions converging to some number, for instance weights (got after 500 iterations) above give me:

```
Min=0.532179; Max=0.532179; Average=0.532179
```

There seems to be something wrong with the network or training configurations. If my network suffered from low variance, at least it would generate a results that are withing the target range. If it suffered from high variance, it would match the target. And now, it just misses the target entirely.

How come error is decreasing and getting pretty low even if predictions are way off? Anyones sees obvious mistakes in my example above? I'm not very experienced with neural networks yet.

Comment: The weights can increase, I've seen trained neural networks with large weights.  I am not seeing anything wrong with your code above. You are normalizing to good ranges.  As to why the training is not converging, that is often complex to answer.  Usual suspects include: skewed data (too many similar outcomes), noisy data, contradictory outcomes.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am not experienced with neural networks. I thought noise would only decrese accuracy. I believe noise might be the problem. I will try reducing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, in my opinion is that you are normalizing between -1 and 1 and use an activation function sigmoid that works with numbers between 0 and 1.
I would suggest you to normalize between 0.1 and 0.9 or use a tanh activation function an retry.

I also would use k-fold cross validation see here http://www.heatonresearch.com/node/2000

Vincenzo